# How to load a QML file from plugin in Qt5

Tags: c++, plugins, qml, qt5

I'm trying to develop a plugin model for my app. The idea is simple:

1. I have an interface that all plugins implement.
2. In my app I have special area where plugin would display UI.

For step 2 in main application I can use Qml Loader component to load an external QML file. So main.qml looks like this:

```
Rectangle {
  width: 500
  height: 500
  Loader {
    id: loader
    source: ???
  }
}
```

I load plugins from c++ with QPluginLoader and my plugin interface looks like this:

```
class ExtensionInterface:public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
      virtual ~ExtensionInterface() {}
      virtual QString getVersion() = 0;
      virtual QQmlComponent* getComponent() = 0;
};
```

So how can i get .qml file from plugin and put it in Loader?

Update:
I add .qml in plugin resource. Now plugin looks like this:[Plugin structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT4A2.png)

To create new QQmlComponent i need qml engine and path to qml file. I know how to pass engine to plugin, but what path should i use? Function from plugin:

```
QQmlComponent* getComponent(){
  QQmlComponent* component = new QQmlComponent(m_QmlEngine, "???");
  return component
}
```

Comment: You can put the file to the plugin's resouce and so return `QQmlComponent` from the plugin using Q_INVOKABLE function.